# Actualizar ComboBox cuando cambien los valores de otro ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

que tal, tengo un problema al momento de querer cambiar los valores de un combobox cuando se cambian otros combos y se da clic a un botón, ya cheque y se esta ejecutando bien el sp que me trae la información, pero esta no se ve reflejada en el combo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos

Anexo un poco del código:

```
private void Find()
    {
        Sequences = new Sequences();
        Proyecto.DataLayer.DbSpacing dataSeq = new DataLayer.DbSpacing();

        list = dataSeq.Find(param1, param2, param3);

        Distributor = new CollectionView(distributorCamList);
        Distributor.MoveCurrentTo(list[0]);
        Distributor.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(distributor_CurrentChange);

        Spacings = new ObservableCollection<Spacing>();
    }
```

Aquí esta el xaml

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_distributor" ItemsSource="{Binding Distributor}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409.584,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="358" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" Height="39" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding vcDistributor}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Ocupo el patrón MVVM y cuando hago la carga inicial de la pantalla, ese combo lo dejo vacío, hasta que cambio otros controles y presiono un botón para que se llene.

Comment: Podrías ampliar tu pregunta con más código? Me gustaría tener evidencia de como asignas la información en el combo, tal vez te funciona la primera carga al control pero las siguientes no, el otro asunto es que no se si trabajas con MVVM o no, si usas el patrón MVVM recuerda que luego de obtener la información debes recargar la capa visual con INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @LeonardoLynx ya actualicé la pregunta, espero por una respuesta. Saludos! :)